# Add WSDL URL from properties into pom

Tags: maven, properties, pom.xml

not sure if this question was already answered, but I've been looking in google and stackoverflow for a while and didn't find something for the requirement I need.

I have a pom.xml file in which I'm defining a property (which is a WSDL URL):

```
<properties>
    <service.wsdl.url>https://myservice.com/testservice.asmx?wsdl</service.wsdl.url>
</properties>
```

And then I have a plugin defined for web service components generation using wsimport:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.12</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>myservice</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsimport</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <wsdlUrls>
                            <wsdlUrl>${service.wsdl.url}</wsdlUrl>
                        </wsdlUrls>
                        <packageName>com.myservice.generated</packageName>
                        <sourceDestDir>src/main/java</sourceDestDir>
                        <args>
                            <arg>-B-XautoNameResolution</arg>
                        </args>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

The question I have is on how can I get the URL from a properties file. I have a properties file called "application.properties" in my src/main/resources folder in which I have a key/value pair:

`service.wsdl.url = https://myservice.com/testservice.asmx?wsdl`

I'd like to do something like:

```
<properties>
    <service.wsdl.url>${service.wsdl.url}</service.wsdl.url>
</properties>
```

I've checking some answers and posts but as mentioned I was not able to find something for my needs.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably make use of the **[`properties-maven-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/usage.html)** as:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <phase>initialize</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <files>
            <file>src/main/resources/application.properties</file>
          </files>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```